# How do I access floats from a dictionary of floats?

Tags: objective-c

I have a property list (`Data.plist`) that contains an array of two dictionaries. Each dictionary is filled with key names (`Factor 1`, `Factor 2`, etc) and floats (`0.87`, `1.15`, etc.). I am trying to access the numbers stored in the dictionary. First I load the dictionary using:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
NSArray *plistData = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];
NSDictionary *dictionaryOne = [plistData objectAtIndex:0];
```

Actually accessing the numbers stored is where I'm having a problem:

```
Float32 conversionFactor = [scyToLCMMen objectForKey:"Factor 50"];
```

I'm getting the error: "`incompatible types in initialization`". What am I doing wrong? Is it not a `Float32`?

Comment: `scyToLCMMen` is just a dictionary that I loaded

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Objective-c containers can only hold obj-c types, so what you get is not a float for sure. What you probably have is NSNumber object and you need to "extract" plain float value from it:

```
Float32 conversionFactor = [[scyToLCMMen objectForKey:"Factor 50"] floatValue];
```

Comment: thank you...this gets rid of the error but now the conversionFactor that it returns is always `1073741824` or `-1073741824` which I think are the max and min values of a float. Why would it be doing this if the number in the dictionary is `0.87`?

Comment: How do you check that value? Try log your variables between each step to see where exactly your float values became wrong

Comment: I check it using an NSLog statement: `Float32 conversionFactor = [[scyToLCMMen objectForKey:eventString] floatValue]; NSLog(@"%d", conversionFactor);`

Comment: for float values you must use %f format, %d expects int value, so wrong type cast may be the issue here

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumber *conversionFactor = [dictionaryOne valueForKey:@"Factor 50"];
float factor = [conversionFactor floatValue];
```

That's what I'd do

Comment: thank you...this gets rid of the error but now the factor that it returns is always `1073741824` or `-1073741824` which I think are the max and min values of a float. Why would it be doing this if the number in the dictionary is `0.87`?

Answer (score 0):

The value is likely an instance of [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
Float32 conversionFactor = [[scyToLCMMen objectForKey:"Factor 50"] floatValue];
```

Comment: thank you...this gets rid of the error but now the conversionFactor that it returns is always `1073741824` or `-1073741824` which I think are the max and min values of a float. Why would it be doing this if the number in the dictionary is `0.87`?